# Why am i getting an incompatible browser message with WebClient?

Tags: c#, http-headers, webclient, microsoft-edge, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to scrape a webpage using .NET using WebClient. However i keep getting an incompatible browser message. Please see below HTML source (unfortunately i cant share the link because it is internal). Somehow the server thinks I am using a version of an incompatible version of IE. I tried setting the user-agent but that didn't have any effect.

```
<!--[if lt IE 10]>

    <div id="incompatible_ie" style="display:block;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-size:14px;text-align:center;margin:20% 0 5em;color:#777">

      <div style="font-size:xx-large;margin-bottom:2em">HOME</div>

      <div>Your browser is not supported by the application.<br>We recommend you use Google Chrome or IE11 without Compatibility Mode.</div>

    </div>

    <script>

      console && console.error("Unsupported browser: Removing #root element to prevent React from loading.");

      document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].removeChild(document.getElementById("root"));

    </script>

    <![endif]-->
```

C#

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.17763");
string html = client.DownloadString(path);
```

Comment: Can you indeed view the page in question in Microsoft Edge?

Comment: Clearly server thinks that your pretending to be browser is not enough. Use Fiddler (or any other tool to capture/compare HTTP traffic), capture traffic from both browser and your code and than [edit] post with result of comparison so someone can help you to fake the rest of headers.

Comment: @rfmodulator yes I can view the page in Edge and Chrome.

Comment: @Joey I've never had this problem after I set an acceptable User-agent string. But I use `HttpWebRequest`/`HttpWebResponse` instead of `WebClient`. YMMV.

Comment: @Joey You might try to give it *exactly* what it's asking for IE11 (on Win10): `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko` or Chrome (on Win10): `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36`

Comment: @rfmodulator thanks i tried that but same result.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thank you, i have never used Fiddler but I will look into it,

Comment: Is that you can only get the above html source or the above is a part of the html source? Have you tried to use other user agent like Chrome user agent to see if the result is the same? I think `client.DownloadString(uri)` will get the whole html code of the page and that part you're showing is just the **conditional comments** partial of the html source.